# Running Web Logic 8.1 Web Service using JAX-RPC Stack on Web Logic 12

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, weblogic12c, jax-rpc

We are currently in the upgrade phase of upgrading to Java7/Weblogic12c (from Java1.5/WebLogic10.1). Our builds is using Maven 2.5.

Our focus is to change as little java code as possible to narrow the scope of where to look for what went wrong in case it did. Hence we would like to ideally not rewrite our code (That would be the next phase that will be handled later).

Our Web services are still using the RPC style like in Web Logic 8.1.

This video basically out line the differences

[Module 13.2 JAXRPC vs. JAXWS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MI2gZMpsP7o)

[image: RPC vs JAXWS]

And in the oracle documentation they describe how the code should be changed to be WS compliant:

[Upgrading an 8.1 Web Logic Web Service to the Web Logic JAX-RPC Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24497/upgrade_ws.htm#CHDDEABA)

Is there no way to use the RPC as is running web logic 12?